# Paypal Integration in Laravel 5.2

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox, shopping-cart, laravel-5

Can anyone provide me the working way of integrate Paypal into my Laravel 5.2 project. ?

I have tried enough, I could not complete.

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have Omnipay working in Laravel 5.2, using a package called [laravel-omnipay](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay).

Comment: I could integrate Paypal into my project using Paypal/Rest api.It works now.